# Set google event reminders with api for Google Calendar from php

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api, reminders

i have a script php for creating a google calendar event.
the script work correctly but the function to set the date wrong.

the script his

```
[...initial statements...]
$event = new Google_Event();
$event->setSummary("test");
$event->setLocation("location");
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime(2014-05-01T10:00:00.000-07:00);
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime(2014-05-01T10:00:00.000-08:00);
$event->setEnd($end);

$reminder = new Google_EventReminders();
$reminder->setUseDefault(false);
$overrides = array("method"=> "popup","minutes" => "15");
$reminder->setOverrides(array($overrides));
$event->setReminders($reminder);

$createdEvent = $service->events->insert('primary', $event);
[...]
```

in event created i ha have two reminders 
email 10 minutes and popup 10 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I got mine to work :)

```
$event = new Google_Event(); //note in the API examples it calls Event(). Apparently, they changed it and didn't update examples.
$event->setSummary($task);
$event->setColorId('4');
$event->setDescription($type);
$event->setLocation($type);
$start = new Google_EventDateTime(); //note in the API examples it calls EventDateTime().
$start->setDateTime($date1);
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_EventDateTime(); //note in the API examples it calls EventDateTime().
$end->setDateTime($date2);
$event->setEnd($end);
$attendee1 = new Google_EventAttendee(); //note in the API examples it calls EventAttendee().
$attendee1->setEmail('myemail@gmail.com'); //make sure you actually put an email address in here

$reminderI = new Google_EventReminder();
$reminderI->setMethod('email');
$reminderI->setMinutes('25');

$reminder = new Google_EventReminders();
$reminder->setUseDefault('false');
$reminder->setOverrides(array($reminderI));
$event->setReminders($reminder);
```

Comment: Hi @Nick,
Although I set the reminder already, but the calendar still show "No notifications set".

Answer (score 1):

I spent a few minutes and figure it out, try this:

```
$reminders = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventReminders();
$reminders->setUseDefault(false);

$reminder = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventReminder();
$method = empty($v['method']) ? 'email' : $v['method'];
$minute = empty($v['minute']) ? '10' : $v['minute'];
$reminder->setMethod($method);
$reminder->setMinutes($minute);

$reminders->setOverrides(array($reminder));

$targetEvent->setReminders($reminders);
```

Notice here `$reminders->setOverrides(array($reminder));` we need to put the `$reminder` in an `array` while calling `$reminders->setOverrides`

I am using the API V3, and I guess you're using V2. Anyway, it should be quite similar.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
$overrides = array("method"=> "popup","minutes" => "15");
```

You are essentially wrapping an array inside an `array` in here:

```
setOverrides(array($overrides));
```

The `override` should instead be an object of type     `Google_Service_Calendar_EventReminder`.